# Log4j2 asynchronous logger default buffer size

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I have a question on the default buffer size when using asynchronous loggers with log4j2. The version of log4j2 is `2.11.2` and is brought in by Spring Boot log4j2 starter 2.1.13.RELEASE.

It looks like different places in the documentation refer to different values.
The [async logger document](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/async.html#SysPropsAllAsync) refers the size as `256 * 1024`. However, the log4j2 [general config document](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#SystemProperties) mentions that the size is `4 * 1024` when running in garbage-free mode, but `256 * 1024` otherwise. And log4j2 and above run by default in [garbage-free mode](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/garbagefree.html).

But, when I start my application with the StatusLogger set to TRACE, the buffer size is shown as 262144 (256 * 1024).

```
DEBUG StatusLogger Creating custom DiscardingAsyncQueueFullPolicy(discardThreshold:INFO)
DEBUG StatusLogger [AsyncContext@685f4c2e] Starting AsyncLogger disruptor for this context with ringbufferSize=262144, waitStrategy=TimeoutBlockingWaitStrategy, exceptionHandler=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerDefaultExceptionHandler@7a4f0f29...
```

I would have assumed the size to be 4096. Has someone else seen this behaviour or am I missing something here?

Thank you.
- Anoop

Answer (score 0):

When Log4j is running in a web application (javax.servlet.Servlet is on the classpath) or the log4j2.enableThreadLocals system property is false the buffer size will be 4 * 1024. Otherwise it is 256 * 1024.

Comment: In my case, log4j2 is running in a web application. So, the default value of log4j2.enableThreadLocals is false. Maybe, I am missing something.

Comment: Yes, that was an “or”. You are in a web app so the value of enableThreadLocals doesn’t matter. The value in a web app is 4 * 1024.

Comment: Got it and that's what I expected. But the logs from `StatusLogger` in the question indicates differently.  

`DEBUG StatusLogger [AsyncContext@685f4c2e] Starting AsyncLogger disruptor for this context with ringbufferSize=262144, waitStrategy=TimeoutBlockingWaitStrategy ...`